# How to connect with WebSocket with Web3?

Tags: web3js, events, infura, websocket

Already referred web3 documentations and other Q-A for web socket connection. Currently using infura as provider.

Comment: Please mark the question as solved if I helped you

Comment: Do you need further guidance or is this question completed?

Comment: @NiklasFeurstein, further discussion available at Discussion Room.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/<yourID>');

const abi = "placeYourABI";

const address = 'yourContractAddress';

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);

contract.getPastEvents('allEvents', {
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}).then(function(events){
    console.log(events);
});
```

Replace the variables. Take note of the URL. Websocket URL is not only different by `wss` at the front.

This code is tested and surely works.

EDIT: Please write why you downvote this answer! It is completely correct.

Comment: How can I check that this connection is open or not?

Comment: Every time it returns, connection not open on send()
Error: connection not open

Comment: Check if your node or ganache-cli process listening at the endpoint provided is up

Comment: @Rudrika I updated my answer

Comment: @Pave, it gives, "connection not open on send()"

Comment: you changed the ws provider to your infura one right?

Comment: Yes, I am using infura provider, and Here WebSocket required ws package installation in npm.

Comment: Let's continue the talk here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98077/room-for-pave-and-rudrika